# Best way to show up a layer for login or input related stuff? [facebook popup style]

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you suggest me a way to show up a div with some contents on some link click?

I mean there is a standard way to load a div and center it in the middle of screen and expand it dynamically based on the contents loaded?

This would save the user to load an entry page just to login for example or input a text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [Leigeber's TinyBox](http://www.leigeber.com/2009/05/javascript-popup-box/). It's very small and comfy.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/

Comment: are there any other ways indipendet from facebook?

Comment: It's not from facebook, it just looks like it. Hence the name 'facebox' not 'book'